# Compare two files content

Tags: bash, awk, grep, compare

I have two files test1.txt and test2.txt

test1.txt contains

```
abc.cde.ccd.eed.12345.5678.txt
abcd.cdde.ccdd.eaed.12346.5688.txt
aabc.cade.cacd.eaed.13345.5078.txt
abzc.cdae.ccda.eaed.29345.1678.txt
abac.cdae.cacd.eead.18145.2678.txt
aabc.cdve.cncd.ened.19945.2345.txt
```

and test2.txt contains

```
12345.5678.txt
29345.1678.txt
18145.2678.txt
10111.2222.txt
```

I want to compare these two files and give me output something like this in bash

In both:

```
abc.cde.ccd.eed.12345.5678.txt
abzc.cdae.ccda.eaed.29345.1678.txt
abac.cdae.cacd.eead.18145.2678.txt
```

Only in test1.txt

```
abcd.cdde.ccdd.eaed.12346.5688.txt
aabc.cade.cacd.eaed.13345.5078.txt
aabc.cdve.cncd.ened.19945.2345.txt
```

Only in test2.txt

```
10111.2222.txt
```

Comment: comm wont compare because test2.txt only contain portion of the contents of test1.txt.

Comment: No diff also doesnt compare since test2 only contains a portion of test1

Comment: @user3845185 it's possible to use comm after some preprocessing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both:

```
grep -f text2.txt text1.txt
```

Output:

```
abc.cde.ccd.eed.12345.5678.txt
abzc.cdae.ccda.eaed.29345.1678.txt
abac.cdae.cacd.eead.18145.2678.txt
```

---

Only in test1.txt:

```
grep -v -f text2.txt text1.txt
```

Output:

```
abcd.cdde.ccdd.eaed.12346.5688.txt
aabc.cade.cacd.eaed.13345.5078.txt
aabc.cdve.cncd.ened.19945.2345.txt
```

---

Only in test2.txt:

```
grep -v -f <( grep -Eo '[0-9]+.[0-9]+.txt' text1.txt) text2.txt
```

Output:

```
10111.2222.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File1 :
abc.cde.ccd.eed.12345.5678.txt
abcd.cdde.ccdd.eaed.12346.5688.txt
aabc.cade.cacd.eaed.13345.5078.txt
abzc.cdae.ccda.eaed.29345.1678.txt
abac.cdae.cacd.eead.18145.2678.txt
aabc.cdve.cncd.ened.19945.2345.txt


File2 :
12345.5678.txt
29345.1678.txt
18145.2678.txt
10111.2222.txt



#!/bin/bash

if [ -e Both.txt ]
then
  rm Both.txt
fi

if [ -e File1.txt ]
then
  rm File1.txt
fi

if [ -e File2.txt ]
then
  rm File2.txt
fi

while read f2line
do
  found=0
  while read f1line
  do
    Both=`echo "$f1line" | grep "$f2line"`
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
      found=1
      echo $Both >> Both.txt
    fi
  done < File1
if [ $found -eq 0 ]
then
  echo $f2line >> File2.txt
fi
done < File2

sort Both.txt > s_Both.txt
sort File1 > s_File1
comm -3 s_File1 s_Both.txt > File1.txt
rm s_File1
rm s_Both.txt
```

Output Files: Both.txt, File1.txt, File2.txt

Answer (score 0):

The following AWK script `script.awk` also does the job:

```
NR == FNR { lines[++i] = $0 }

NR > FNR { patterns[++j] = $0 }

END {
    for (p_index in patterns)
        for (l_index in lines)
            if (index(lines[l_index], patterns[p_index]) > 0) {
                lines_match[l_index] = 1
                patterns_match[p_index] = 1
            }

    print "Lines only in first file:"
    for (l_index in lines)
        if (!(l_index in lines_match)) 
            print lines[l_index]

    print "Lines only in second file:"
    for (p_index in patterns)
        if (! (p_index in patterns_match)) 
            print patterns[p_index]

    print "Lines in both files:"
    for (l_index in lines)
        if (l_index in lines_match)
            print lines[l_index]
}
```

It can be called as follows:

```
awk -f script.awk test1.txt test2.txt
```

Note that the script does not make any assumptions about the structure of the data in the two files. It simply assumes that the lines in `test2.txt` are potential substrings of the lines in `test1.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

This formulation might be solved using `comm` from GNU Coreutils:

Sort second file at first:

```
sort -o test2.txt test2.txt;
```

Then use commands to show lines:

```
# unique to test1.txt
cut -d '.' -f 1-4 --complement test1.txt | sort | comm -23 - test2.txt
# unique to test2.txt
cut -d '.' -f 1-4 --complement test1.txt | sort | comm -13 - test2.txt
# that appear in both files
cut -d '.' -f 1-4 --complement test1.txt | sort | comm -12 - test2.txt
```

**Explanation**:

```
# 1. Extract all but first four fields from test1.txt
cut -d '.' -f 1-4 --complement test1.txt
# 2. Here '-' replaces standard input
comm -3 - test2.txt
```